# Not able to cast response to particular list object in Java

Tags: java

I'm getting response from a webservice as

```
[{Id=100, value=1815401000238}, {Id=101, value=1815401000244}]
```

Here I'm casting the value to list object as

```
List<Map<String, String>> leadIds
```

Here I'm passing the response to the method

```
ServiceUtil.Status(leadIds);
```

leadIds has the above response

Here is the method definition

```
 public Response updateStatus(List<Map<String, String>> leadIds) {
```

So that I can cast and iterate. But ,it throws me error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
```

What exactly should be casted? I guess its a list object.

Comment: @Eran, I can't put the code here. But, I'm expecting that type of response should be cast to the object.

Comment: @Eran I've put the method definition. Please check

Comment: I don't see any code that does any casting.

Comment: @Eran, I'm passing that output to that method which is expecting that response.

Comment: @Nizam you really need to show us the line of code that does the casting for us to be of any help.

Comment: Try to cast it to `Map<String, String>` instead of `List<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: @Hindol, its should be a list object which internally has map object again, right

Comment: From the error message `LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Map$Entry` it seems otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>` instead of `List<Map<String, String>>` when doing casting

Comment: I will try and let you know Safwan